# upload pdf, csv and other file type in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload, upload

code to upload csv, pdf and other

```
$config['allowed_types'] = "application/pdf|pdf|application/octet-stream|csv";
```

on

```
print_r($_FILES);
```

gives
for csv

```
Array ( [userfile] => Array ( [name] => file.csv [type] => application/octet-stream [tmp_name] => C:\xampp\tmp\php4FD2.tmp [error] => 0 [size] => 7 ) )
```

for pdf

```
Array ( [userfile] => Array ( [name] => doc.pdf [type] => application/pdf [tmp_name] => C:\xampp\tmp\phpA4E5.tmp [error] => 0 [size] => 127670 ) )
```

on

```
$this->upload->display_errors()
```

gives for both

```
Array ( [error] => 1 [msg] => The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed. )
```

anyone hving  idea wat is the problem

i also tried ans from other que like this
in mimes.php

```
'pdf'   =>      array('application/pdf', 'application/x-pdf', 'application/x-download','application/x-download', 'binary/octet-stream', 'application/unknown', 'application/force-download'),
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

please add this in your application\config\mimes.php file.

```
'csv'   =>  array('text/x-comma-separated-values', 'text/comma-separated-values', 'application/octet-stream', 'application/vnd.ms-excel', 'application/x-csv', 'text/x-csv', 'text/csv', 'application/csv', 'application/excel', 'application/vnd.msexcel')

'pdf'   =>  array('application/pdf', 'application/x-download')
```

now on upload function in controller use

```
$config['allowed_types'] = 'pdf|csv';

$this->load->library('upload', $config);

$this->upload->initialize($config);`
```

Comment: i was missing '$this->upload->initialize($config);'

Comment: ok , what kind of file is .fr3 files? pdf is application, html is text, fr3 is?

Comment: i dont't know. But you can print $_FILES and check the mime type.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem when the program receives multiples files, i saw that the method not resets the complete data from the current file that is uploading.

The problem was solved separating the function

> $this->load->library('upload', $config);

to:

> $this->load->library('upload');
>
> $this->upload->initialize($config);

```
function fn_upload_file($file_name, $path, $types = 'gif|jpg|jpeg|png|mp3|mpeg') {
    $config = array();
    $config['upload_path'] = $path;
    $config['allowed_types'] = $types;
    $config['max_size']    = '15000000';
     
    $this->load->library('upload');
    
    $this->upload->initialize($config);
    
    if(!is_dir($path)){
        @mkdir($path, 0777, true);
    }
    
    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload($file_name)) {
        throw new Exception($this->upload->display_errors());
    } else {
        return $this->upload->data();
    }
}
```

Cause when i used the  $this->upload->data(); to see with